# on the use of the datagridview comboboxcolumn in vb.net

Tags: datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

I have a dataset with 2 tables. The first table contains some string literals in the first column and in the second column I have numerical code for each of these strings.
In the second table I have a column that contains the numerical codes as in the first table.
My problem is to have a datagridview that displays the information in table 2 while replacing the numerical codes by their string counterparts.
I used a comboboxcolumn and the project generates ok but the comboboxcolumn is empty.
I would appreciate any help. Thanks.
Tried adding a comboboxcolumn to the datagridview. I suspect I not grasping the meaning of the datapropertyname property.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).